# Real time data communication between RaspberryPi 3 and an Android device

Tags: android, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I want to send data between RaspberryPi 3 and an android app, preferably over Wi-Fi.

I've sent data between RPi 1 model B and android before but through USB Tethering. Now using RPI 3 model B, so thought of sending through Wi-Fi.

Can anyone guide me on how to do it ? Any little help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you send data through usb tethering? And how did you connect the devices?

Comment: Communication between two applications on two devices connected by wifi is done by a server application and a client app.

Comment: What you have to do depends on the type of data you want to communicate. You should give better info.

Comment: @greenapps : I've used Socket communication . Client- Server model

Comment: I just want to send an integer to RPi. They are just control signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already programming in Java for the Android client, one way to go forward could be to install Java on the Pi and then use something as simple as basic sockets. Depends on your use case, though.

Take Oracle's [All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) as an example, write a server side program to run on the Pi with ServerSocket:

```
    try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    ) {
        while (dataProvider.isDataAvailable()) {
            out.println(dataProvider.getData());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO
    }
```

Then connect to the server from the Android App:

```
    try (
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        while (true) {
            parseData(in.readLine());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I programmed in basic HTML and JS, and used Cordova TCP Socket APIs.

Comment: This is working with USB tethering .  But when I tried to connect RPi and the App , the code didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but with "the code didn't work" nobody will be able or willing to help you. You even "unaccepted" the answer, although it works and you obviously run into a different problem.

Comment: Hello guys , the problem was with the static IP I've set.

Comment: @Micheal Kanis - Sorry I didn't mean your code is not working. The code that I was already using wasn't working ( because the static IP wasn't correct).